# List box with two columns in JSP

Tags: html, jsp

List Box with two columns in JSP and also is it possible to sort the order of the two columns like either ascending or descending based on each user's requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [table](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp). And this [jQuery](http://jquery.com) plugin: [tablesorter.com](http://tablesorter.com)

Comment: If I use a table, I wont be able to select a row. I also want the requirement of selecting a row and passing its value to the code.So either list box or Drop down where I can pass the value. Are there any plugins for these?